# Response() in laravel 5.6 look up folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm using laravel 5.6 and using the following code:

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

My problem is I cant seem to find what folder `pathToFile` is pointing to. I tried the `public/`folder, but that doesn't appear to be it.

Comment: Where did you put the file? if you want to access files inside the public folder, try doing this: `response()->file(public_path($pathToFile))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel stores files under `/storage` which is by default hidden to public.

If you want to make them publicly available you need to issue command `php artisan storage:link`

After that all your files in your `/storage` directory will be accessible in your `http:/domainname/storage` via for example `asset('storage/yourfile');`